# The IRS collects property taxes?

Tags: united-states, irs, property-taxes

I read [an article on Nicholas Cage squandering his fortune](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/01/19/how-nicholas-cage-once-blew-his-entire-150-million-fortune.html) and among other things it says he was "...eventually facing foreclosure on several properties and owing the IRS $6.3 million in property taxes".

How can he owe the IRS property taxes? I thought that property taxes were state taxes only in the United States.

Comment: Income tax on capital gains on the buying and selling of property??

Answer (score 3):

No, the IRS doesn't collect property tax.

Most of the articles about this are short on substance, but from statements Nicolas Cage made, it sounds like he owed back-income tax that resulted in the IRS putting a lien on his real-estate holdings.

He may also have had property tax issues with local government, but that would be a separate issue from the IRS.

Edit: This [article](http://www.businessinsider.com/2008/9/nicolas-cage-paying-666-000-for-tax-evasion-after-deducting-gulfstream-jet) seems solid, suggests Cage's back-tax issues are due to improperly deducting personal expenses.